# Helm - Subchart dependent on other subchart

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I have a Parent chart with two sub-charts `subchart1` and `postgres` and there is a `pre-install` job in `subchart1` which creates necessary tables/schema's for `subchart1` service, where the job is in turn dependent on `postgres` sub-chart to be installed first, so when I install the parent chart with `pre-install` job hook, it fails because the `postgres` sub-chart is not installed yet.

To overcome this problem I changed job from `pre-install` to `post-install or install`, used `initContainer` to wait until `postgres` sub-chart is installed before starting the job,

the issue now I am facing is how to make sure the job is run  before installing the `subchart1` when doing an `subchart1` upgrade

One way I can think of is have a `initContainer` in the `subchart1` to wait until the job is finished, how to notify `subchart1` that the job is finished

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using helm concepts, you can use k8s concepts to solve this problem.
You can add a k8s job to your `subchart1` which runs to completion and creates the needed tables. The `initContainer` in other pods can be used to wait for the k8s job to complete. The k8s job can fail if the needed dependency `postgres` is not up. On failure, k8s will make sure to re-run the job. The job is ran to completion.

Rather than using init-containers to wait, you can also choose to use liveness and readiness-probe. The readiness probe is generally implemented using /ready API. If the readiness-probe fails, no tarffic is sent to the POD. If liveness-probe fails, the POD is restarted. See [k8s docs on configuring liveness and readiness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/)

Comment: how to notify subchart1 that the job is finished?

Comment: my suggestion is to not use the helm concepts for handling this problem. The suggestion is to use k8s concepts. I have updated the answer to clarify the same.

Comment: but we have a strict notion on using helm to accomplish this, is there a way to accomplish this via helm, I am mainly interested in `how to notify deployments in the subchart1 that the subchart1 job is finished i.e., necessary tables are created, you can start Pod creation, service creation etc`

Comment: @CodingNinja was it possible to make a subchart dependent on other subchart ?